# adding '/' to numeric values in R

Tags: r, regex

i have numeric values that have nchar = 7 or 8.

For instance let's say I have these two values :

```
1234567
12345678
```

what I want do is:

```
If nchar(x) = 7
```

then add `/` after the 1st value and 3rd value.

So, my results would look like this:

```
1/23/4567
```

`if nchar(x) = 8`, then add `/` after the 2nd and 4th value.
Results: `12/34/5678`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` here:

```
x <- "12345678"
sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})(\\d{4})$", "\\1/\\2/\\3", x)
```

### Demo

Comment: This is really a concise option.  I was thinking in a bit off track

Comment: @akrun Which is rare, as you are the top R user on the site :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (we’re counting from the end, which simplifies things tremendously):

```
stringr::str_replace(num, '(..)(....)$', '/\\1/\\2')
```

As an alternative, since you’re dealing with numbers, consider using *numeric* operations:

```
paste(num %/% 1e6, num %% 1e6 %/% 1e4, num %% 1e4, sep = '/')
```

(This performs integer division and remainder operations to extract the relevant groups of digits.)

Note that these will give different results if your numbers have leading zeros. Depending on what you want to do in such a case, the first (or second) solution might not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be with regex?

how about:

```
test <- '1234567'
n <- nchar(test)

test_split <- strsplit(test, '')[[1]]

paste0(paste0(test_split[1:(n - 6)], collapse = ''), '/',
       paste0(test_split[(n - 5):(n - 4)], collapse = ''), '/',
       paste0(test_split[(n - 3):n], collapse = ''))
```

Comment: It doesn’t *have* to be (see also my answer) but why make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: I don't think I'd consider this answer more complicated. If anything, your answer is more difficult to understand than this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- nchar(x)
paste(substr(x, 1, n - 6), 
      substr(x, n - 5, n - 4), 
      substr(x, n - 3, n), 
      sep = '/')
```

Seems to be a little faster than using `sub`

```
x <- sample(c("12345678", "1234567"), 1e6, T)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  sub   = {sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})(\\d{4})$", "\\1/\\2/\\3", x)},
  paste = { n <- nchar(x)
            paste(substr(x, 1, n - 6), 
                  substr(x, n - 5, n - 4), 
                  substr(x, n - 3, n), 
                  sep = '/')},
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#    sub 868.1314 897.1632 942.0971 926.6259 953.9557 1137.5071    10
#  paste 687.1708 703.5417 741.0434 714.0114 766.5217  914.2754    10
```

Comment: I like the `substr` as it is easier to understand, but a microbenchmark on this small data is meaningless

Comment: @akrun you're right. Edited to include a test for character vector of length `1e6`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `formatC` with a bit of hacking to account for the variable marking lengths:

```
formatC(c(1234567,12345678)/100, big.mark="/", big.interval=2, decimal.mark="", mode="double", digits=8)
[1] "1/23/4567"  "12/34/5678"
```

Essentially you are shifting the last two digits to the other side of the decimal point, which you make invisible, and then use `/` big marks for every two digits to the left of the decimal point.